# If checkbox checked offset (0,1) value date

Tags: vba, excel

Hello what I am trying to do is if check box is is checked then Offset (0,1) .value = Date
There is a lot of check box's and I was wondering if there is a easy way to do this. Also note that I am using Active X Check box's.

Thanks

Comment: question is lacking details but regardless, i posted a sample code which will check whether an embedded `Checkbox` is checked or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
        CheckBox1.TopLeftCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Date
    Else
        CheckBox1.TopLeftCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = vbNullString
    End If
End Sub
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Let us know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
If Activesheet.OLEObjects("Checkbox1").Object.Value = True Then
'~~> insert code here
    Msgbox "Checked"
Else
'~~> insert code here    
    Msgbox "UnChecked"
End If
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i only assumed that your `Checkbox` name is `Checkbox1`, you need to identify it first. this is just a guide how to check a checkbox's state (checked or unchecked). And you said you have many, so i guess you have to iterate through it. Say `For Each` statement?

Comment: For Example `If Me.Checkbox1 = true then` this is where i need to take the cell that the check box is in of offset (0,1)

Comment: we are talking of `Embedded Checkbox` here right? not the `UserForm` checkbox? or was it? sorry for assuming :)

Comment: It Is an Embedded Checkbox yes

Comment: I editted my post. I still didn't get how to pinpoint the location of the checkbox though. Just how to check its status.